# How to disable codesign check on Logic Pro X plug-ins?

Tags: crash, plugins, code-signing

1. I run [Logic Pro X](https://www.apple.com/logic-pro/) and other software to make music, and some third party plugins make the program crash if they get a:

   ```
   Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)
   ```

   I can solve this problem by `codesign -f -s - <file>` but id rather not to, is there a way to disable code signature check? so it wont even give me an error and wont check it?

*I assume the answer is no so hence my second question:*

2. i need to run `sudo codesign -f -s -`  on a .bundle file thats inside a a Resource folder inside a .component (a package), and i have A LOT of these to go through, for example:

   - Plugin_2.component -> Resources -> ***Plugin_2.bundle***
   - Plugin_3.component -> Resources -> ***Plugin_3.bundle***

Is there a way to make a command to do it automatically?

I was thinking maybe in automator? something to make it do these 2 steps:

1. look for a .bundle file inside a Resource folder in a package
2. run `sudo codesign -f -s -`  on it

Is that possible? maybe make it in Automator and add it to Services in the right click menu? or to make it scan a whole folder with `.component`?

Answer (score 2):

after some trial and error i managed to solve it easily with the following command in terminal

```
find . -name "*.bundle" -execdir sudo codesign -f -s - {} \;
```

`find . -name "*.EXTENSION"` is responsible for finding the certain file extension in a directory

`-execdir YOUR COMMAND {} \;` is responsible to executing the command.
using `-execdir` -> on the results of the previous find command ( `{}` )

fairly simple after all, hope this can help someone in the future

Comment: Thanks for this Gobee - it sounds quite useful, given the failure rate of AU scans in recent versions of Logic. Forgive my ignorance, but what command would need to precede this in order to direct its search to, say, just the Components plugin folder?